# Why RequestMapping annotation does't work with class in springboot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, request-mapping

I'm trying to learn springbott with a sample. When I tried to call a restcontroller that was defined on the class, I got 404 error.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class ReservationResource {

    public ResponseEntity<ReservationResponse> getAvaliableRooms(
            @RequestParam(value = "checkin") @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE) LocalDate checkin,
            @RequestParam(value = "checkout") @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE) LocalDate checkout) {

        return new ResponseEntity<>(new ReservationResponse(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

*This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Wed Aug 16 16:18:05 EEST 2017
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available*

But when I tried like below It worked!

```
@RestController
public class ReservationResource {

    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public ResponseEntity<ReservationResponse> getAvaliableRooms(
            @RequestParam(value = "checkin") @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE) LocalDate checkin,
            @RequestParam(value = "checkout") @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE) LocalDate checkout) {

        return new ResponseEntity<>(new ReservationResponse(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Why this differences occured? By the way I follow an example, the developer defined it like section one!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the annotation @RestController means that your class will act as @Controller and all methods defined inside will have by default a @ResponseBody

But you need to define the specific path for each method inside your Controller.

For instance you could do:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class ReservationResource {

    @RequestMapping("/") 
    public ResponseEntity<ReservationResponse> getAvaliableRooms(
            @RequestParam(value = "checkin") @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE) LocalDate checkin,
            @RequestParam(value = "checkout") @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE) LocalDate checkout) {

        return new ResponseEntity<>(new ReservationResponse(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/second") 
    public ResponseEntity<ReservationResponse> getAvaliableRooms(
                @RequestParam(value = "checkin") @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE) LocalDate checkin,
                @RequestParam(value = "checkout") @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE) LocalDate checkout) {

            return new ResponseEntity<>(new ReservationResponse(), HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    }
```

With this configuration you have defined a path in /test/ with GET method and other "/test/second" also GET, but by deafult all yours paths will start by "/test"

If you decide to use @RequestMapping at method level you can modify the path inside the same class.

For instance:

```
@RestController
public class ReservationResource {

        @RequestMapping("/test") 
        public ResponseEntity<ReservationResponse> getAvaliableRooms(
                @RequestParam(value = "checkin") @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE) LocalDate checkin,
                @RequestParam(value = "checkout") @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE) LocalDate checkout) {

            return new ResponseEntity<>(new ReservationResponse(), HttpStatus.OK);
        }

        @RequestMapping("/second") 
        public ResponseEntity<ReservationResponse> getAvaliableRooms(
                    @RequestParam(value = "checkin") @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE) LocalDate checkin,
                    @RequestParam(value = "checkout") @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE) LocalDate checkout) {

                return new ResponseEntity<>(new ReservationResponse(), HttpStatus.OK);
            }
        }
```

And both URL would be accessible with "/test" and "/second"

Comment: @GetMapping("/") simply doesn't work. While @GetMapping("") does work in this scenario where you use class-level RequestMapping.

Answer (score 2):

You have to annotate your method with `@RequestMapping`. The Controller cant know which method should be executed if there is no annotation.

```
@RequestMapping("/test")
Class Level

@RequestMapping
Mehtod Level

Reachable = http://localhost:8080/test
```

---

```
@RequestMapping("/test")
Class Level

@RequestMapping("/abc")
Mehtod Level

Reachable = http://localhost:8080/test/abc
```

---

```
@RequestMapping("/test")
Class Level

@RequestMapping("/abc")
Mehtod Level

@RequestMapping("/def")
Mehtod Level

Reachable = http://localhost:8080/test/abc
Reachable = http://localhost:8080/test/def
```

Comment: but now, there is just one method?

Comment: yes, on class level its just the prefix url. On method level you can define the suffix. Or leave class level emtpy and just set your mapping on method level. its your choice

Answer (score 1):

because if you Use @RequestMapping at class level it will not know which method to execute as your class can have multiple methods

Comment: but now, there is just one method?

Answer (score 1):

`/test` is a class level mapping for the controller and then in order to make the `getAvaliableRooms()` `public` method eligible serving for requests you need to add `@RequestMapping("")` to your `getAvaliableRooms()` method as shown below:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping("")
    public ResponseEntity<ReservationResponse> getAvaliableRooms(
        @RequestParam(value = "checkin") @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE) 
                   LocalDate checkin,
        @RequestParam(value = "checkout") @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE) 
               LocalDate checkout) {

       return new ResponseEntity<>(new ReservationResponse(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

In other words, you are explicitly telling the Spring container that which of the `public` methods inside the controller class is actually meant for serving the requests.